# How to save form params in the hasMany side of a one to many relationship in grails

Tags: forms, grails, data-binding, parameters

I have one to many relationship between a Post which has many comments of the domain Comment. In my gsp I´m showing a blog post with it´s comments below, at the end, there is form a user can fill out in order to create a new comment. So I´m passing the params filled in the form to a controller in order to save the new comment, but I´m not sure if I have to do it in the PostController (one side) or in the CommentController (many side). And second how exactly should I save the new comment, I used this, CommentController:

```
def save() {
    def p = new Comment(params)
    p.save()
    redirect(action: 'blog', controller: 'Post', params: params)
}
```

Which at the end redirects to the PostController where I render the post view with the all the content including the new comment, PostController

```
def blog()
{
    def post = Post.get(params.id)
    def entra = Post.findById(params.id)
    [post: post, articulos: entra]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> " but I´m not sure if I have to do it in the PostController (one side)
>   or in the CommentController (many side)."

Controllers are not domain objects and are not involved in the relationship between Post and Comment. You can create a controller called PoopyCakaController and do the logic there. It is really irrelevant. Given that info, in my opinion, I guess it depends on whether multiple objects can have comments. If post owns those comments and no other objects have comments, do it in the post controller, otherwise do it in the comment controller.

> "And second how exactly should I save the new comment, I used this,
>   CommentController:"

Is that working for you? If so, that's fine. If it is not working for you, post what the problem is including any errors you are getting.

Comment: Thank you, firts, Post is the owner of the comments in fact, Post domain has the "hasMany = [statements: Comment]" property and Comment domain has the "belongsTo= [post: Post] property. And second, it is not working but no error appearing, is just I checked the database after I submmit a coomment and I saw nothing there